# "Your vote has been recorded" popup should close itself automatically after few seconds

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, popups

Why do we need to explicitly dismiss the "Your vote has been recorded" notification after submitting or retracting a close vote? I think it should timeout automatically after a few seconds. I think I even remember it was like this at one time; if so, why was it changed?

Comment: The popup confirming that your vote has been retracted also does not go away (discovered while repro-ing)

Comment: Are you referring to a notice that pops up if you have less than 125 (ish?) rep and try to downvote a post? I just tried that and it did get automatically dismissed after a while (albeit I prefer it gone sooner).

Comment: No, I'm talking about what happens when I cast a close vote for a question.

Comment: @bobble I assume there's common code for these notifications. Close votes are what I submit most.

Comment: I don't mind it, I hardly ever notice the pop-up, as it sits on top of the topbar. When I VTC a question I generally don't need any other interaction with that question anymore, and moving away to a different page makes the pop-up disappear automatically.

Comment: Considering such votes are important and don't always succeed on first try, I recommend against this feature. Connectivity issues are not as rare as I'd like on SE.

Comment: @Mast If the vote doesn't succeed, the VTC dialogue won't close.

Comment: FYI, it does close itself automatically. It just takes a little bit longer than expected/desired. Per my observation, it's displayed for 20 seconds. The same also happens with the "You’re no longer following this question" message that one gets after unfollowing a question.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Should I just delete the question since it was based on an incorrect premise, or would you like to post that as an answer?

Comment: @Barmar Because the question has an upvoted answer, the system won't let you delete the question anyway. Okay, let me post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 10):

I think the current behavior is fine — necessary, even. Not everyone will be able to notice and read a message like that in a few seconds. According to [W3's page for WCAG Success Criterion 2.2.3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/no-timing.html):

> People with low vision need more time to locate things on screen and to read. People who are blind and using screen readers may need more time to understand screen layouts, to find information and to operate controls. People who have cognitive or language limitations need more time to read and to understand. People who are deaf and communicate in sign language may need more time to read information printed in text (which may be a second language for some).

While I don't fit into any of those categories, having messages disappear after a few seconds means that I'll miss what it said if my eyes are anywhere other than near the top of the screen (where the message appears), only seeing a flash in my peripheral vision. (And it makes it a pain to get screenshots if you're trying to create a visual guide to post to meta.)

Comment: I don't see that text on the page you linked to, did you post the correct link? But I think that guideline can be moderated when it's not critical to read the message. You can tell that the close vote was recorded because the VTC dialogue was closed.

Comment: @Barmar The link was an off by 0.0.1 error on my part. As for closing the dialog, it may still happen when there's a network error that prevents the vote from happening, depending on the timing. As for the information not being critical, that's not possible for the user to determine when it's just a flash somewhere on screen that they didn't get the chance to read.

Answer (score 1):

It does actually get closed automatically; it just takes a little longer than expected/desired.

Per my observation, that toast message gets displayed for exactly 20 seconds and then disappears automatically if not manually dismissed before then. This (extended) delay also happens with other toast messages. For example, I noticed it with the "You’re no longer following this question" message that one gets after unfollowing a question.

Although I think that 20 seconds is a little too long for a short message and it annoyed me quite a few times, if this improves accessibility as explained in [Laurel's answer](/a/381367), I can personally live with it. I've just learned to ignore it anyway.